# How can I use URL rewriting to redirect a domain to a subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my domain to go to my subdomain with the following `.htaccess` configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC ]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding some clarification as to exactly what is happening, since the above configuration isn't getting you where you want to be. Where is it taking you and what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Space is not allowed after NC flag, replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```